# treemodel js - how to get nest level while walking the tree

Tags: treemodel

Api does not provide any information how deep we are in the tree while walking.
Do You have any ideas how to get such information?

```
root.walk(function (node) {
     console.log('Nesting level' + node.??) 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the length of the path of the node:

```
root.walk(function (node) {
  console.log('Nesting level ' + node.getPath().length);
});
```

edit: Efficiency wise, each time you call `getPath` it follows the parent links up to the root, so it's linear to the node depth.

Comment: sure, thank you. Is it optimal for big trees to ask each time for path ?